# Understanding reason for 403 Forbidden error

Tags: http-status-code-403

I'm trying to run a web application that I've built in an iframe on another domain. I'm able to load the page within the iframe, but any ajax requests on the page result in a 403 error as per below:

```
Request URL: https://test.mydomain.com/get_extra_services/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 207.38.86.14:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1382
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 22:57:41 GMT
Server: nginx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.2146753382.1592180975; _gid=GA1.2.1219012919.1592286837
DNT: 1
Host: test.mydomain.com
Origin: https://test.mydomain.com
Referer: https://test.mydomain.com/order/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken: null
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
serviceid: 18
checked: 1
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup CORS to make requests from a different domain.

https://enable-cors.org/